# Как сделать готовое к использованию приложение на electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Есть у меня установленный Electron. Я написал html, js, package.json. Открываю Electron, переношу туда свой html файл, приложение запускается. И что теперь? А как другу показать? "Установи electron, вот я тебе скинул файлы, открой electron, перенеси туда в специальное окошко файл с расширением .html, смотри, какое у меня красивое приложение." А нельзя как-то нормально сделать? Как сделать так, что бы я скинул другу, ну, может папку, но что бы там нужно было открыть 1 файл для запуска моего приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [Electron packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager).

Чтобы установить пишем:

```
$ npm install electron-packager --save-dev
```

Потом в `package.json` добавляем в `"scripts"`:

```
"scripts": {
    "pack": "electron-packager <тут путь к папке программы> <название программы> --platform=win32 --arch=x64"
}
```

И, да, запускать надо так:

```
npm run pack
```

*P.S. Правда, получиться не один файл, а целая папочка файлов..*

Comment: Через "pack" - ничего не происходило. Посидел, покрехтел, попробовал что нибудь своять, даже почитал на гитхабе инструкции, посмотрел на ютубе туториалы, в итоге просто с глазами в разные стороны, со слюной у рта, считая себя дебилом, команду `electron-packager <тут путь к папке программы> <название программы> --platform=win32 --arch=x64` положил в "start" и всё заработало после $ npm start. Спасибо)

Comment: Я просто забыл уточнить, что надо запускать так: `npm run pack`))))

Comment: ахаха) Все-равно спасибо.